# Get particular child node class name javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get particular child node(i.e. i want only div). how can i do this. This is my code

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
        <input type="text">
        <div class="nod1"></div>
        <input type="text">
        <div class="nod2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
    <script>
    var tst=document.getElementById('test');
    var childrens=tst.children;
    for(var i=0; i<childrens.length; i++){
        console.log(childrens[i]);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get"?

Comment: is this what you need? document.getElementsByClassName("nod1")

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
for(var i=0; i<childrens.length; i++){
    console.log(childrens[i].className);
}
```

Comment: Without clear question..??have you seen that he is asking for the class name of those child,sorry @arkascha we are assumed like that,

Comment: No, sorry, I have seen nothing about a class name, only about a node and an id. And since the question was also tagged with php he could have been searching for a solution using php-dom. Or for a regex extraction of the div section of the html markup he posted. May possibilities. But since the OP did not ask a clear question you just made a guess. All fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
<script>
var tst=document.getElementById('test');
var childrens=tst.children;
for(var i=0; i<childrens.length; i++){
    if(childrens[i].tagName=='div')
        console.log(childrens[i]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
    var tst = document.getElementById('test');
    var childrens = tst.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < childrens.length; i++) {
        if (childrens[i].tagName == "DIV") {
            alert("its a div");
         }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: childrens[i].tagName == "DIV" working but childrens[i].tagName == "div" not working. Is there any specific reason